# jQuery live sibling-selector not working

Tags: css-selectors, jquery

I have this CSS selector, which just won't bind `.live()`, but works perfectly with `.bind()`:

`$('.treeView li ~ :has("ul")').prev('li')`

I've read somewhere, that using the `.prev()` and `.next()` could be troublesome coupled with `.live()`, so I wanted to create an pure CSS selector (or ANYTHING that works with `.live()`!) to do the job - but I just can't figure it out!

Here's what I want to do:
Select all `li`-elements, which is followed by an `li` containing an `ul`.

Here's an HTML markup example, I want to select the ones where the comment says "selected"

```
<div class="treeView" id="processSegmentsTree">
    <ul>
        <li>Ostetanke</li>    //selected
        <li>
            <ul>
                <li>Tank 1</li>
                <li>Tank 2</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Presse</li>    //selected
        <li>
            <ul>
                <li>Sub-leaf 1</li>
                <li>Sub-leaf 2</li>    //selected
                <li>
                    <ul>
                        <li>test</li>
                        <li>test</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Any help is much appreciated, since this is a bit of a thorn in my eye :(

Comment: Well [there is no previous sibling selector in CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817792/css-previous-sibling-selector), and jQuery doesn't implement one of its own...

Comment: I am well aware of that (thourght I made that clear :P), I am looking for a way to achieve what I need, and make it work with the `.live()` event system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such Selector to accomplish this task.

What I highly recommend you to do is to add ANYTHING as a flag to use when selecting your desired elements.
add attribute, wrapper, ANYTHING YOU WANT, then the task will be as easy as it should be.

Comment: Yeah, you're probably right. What I was after what a way to add new branches and leafs to a treeView, and not have to worry about re-binding event handlers. But now that I've actually implemented all the re-binding, I see that your suggestion is way simpler than multi-line, hairy CSS-selectors. Thanks for the help! :)

Answer (score 0):

This may work: // not css selector

```
$(".treeView li:has('ul')").prev();
```

Comment: The problem is to get rid of `prev()` because it does not work together with `live`.

Comment: @Thor Jacobsen Hi friend, there is no css selector that can satisfied your aim. jQuery permit us to use css selectors and also it provides us many of its own process to make query on dom/elements which is not accepted in css.

Comment: @Thor do u have any chance to generate ul-li dynamically?